# Symfony @Translatable with Entity Manager's refresh

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, internationalization, entitymanager

I am successfully using StofDoctrineExtension Bundle to work with entity translations.
Therefore, my properties in the entities have the @Translable - annotation above.

When I want to show an entity in a specific language with related Entities (for which a translation entry in the database exists), I get the following problem:

Asuming I have an author entity that is mapped to a contact entity (OneToOne) and I want to show the author details in the language "fr_fr", I am using the following code:

```
    $author = ...;
    $author->setTranslatableLocale('fr_fr');
    $this->get('fos_user.entity_manager')->refresh($author);
```

This code is translating the author into the language "fr_fr" - but the mapped contact entity is not being translated into the target language "fr_fr". I am of course already using the cascade=refresh option within the author entity's mapping on contact:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AuthorContact", inversedBy="author", 
   cascade={"persist", "remove", "refresh"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contact_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $contact;
```

When I use the following "extra lines" within my controller to fetch for the author, I get the translation for both entities:

```
    $author = ...;
    $author->setTranslatableLocale('fr_fr');
    $author->getContact()->setTranslatableLocale('fr_fr');
    $this->get('fos_user.entity_manager')->refresh($author);
    $this->get('fos_user.entity_manager')->refresh($author->getContact());
```

For my taste, this is kind of ugly AND why does it not work by using the "cascade=refresh" option anyways?

@edit: I think this is a bug of the cascade refresh?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not cascade persist but cascade localization. There is no such ability mentioned in the docs. In your case translation is done by `TranslatableListener` in the `postLoad` event. To define the locale [getTranslatableLocale](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/TranslatableListener.php#L301) method is used.

There are several ways to make the above code work.

1. Define cascade saving in the `setTranslatableLocale` method

   public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
   {
        $this->locale = $locale;
        $this->contact->setTranslatableLocale($locale);
   }
2. Don't use the `@Locale` annotation and rely on the `locale` of `TranslatableListener`:

   $this->translatableListener->setTranslatableLocale('fr_fr');

This will work for both: `TranslatableListener` and `TranslationWalker`. For the latter you can also set hint with locale - this will force to load all entities in the needed locale.

> $query->setHint(
>       \Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE,
>       'fr_fr'
>   );

[link](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#using-orm-query-hint)

3. Override the `TranslatableListener`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna take your first approach, even if the other two also sound really nice :) Maybe later, when I work good with the "hints", I will take the "hint-approach".